# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline have the approve as the original requestor

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have created Azure DevOps (formerly VSTS and TFS) Release Pipelines created with multistages and pre-approval and post-approval groups.  What I would like to do is add an additional person - the originator of the build artifact (the developer who instigated the triggers or known as the `RELEASE_REQUESTEDFOR`) for one of the stages.  I want to add that single person as an Approver automatically.  Is that even possible?

Comment: I don't think this feature exists. But,you can achieve that with some code,You can create a script who change the pre/post-approval to the creator when running build.
Let me know if you would like some help with that.

Comment: Are you talking about modifying the Release Pipeline via the REST API on-the-fly?

Comment: Yep, i know this is bad solution.. but it seems the only working one.

Comment: It's doable, but it's ugly.  Yeah, I'm not wasting time for such a small enhancement for a small group of developers.  This is something the ADO developers can just add as a checkbox in some future enhancement.